# Snowflake - parsing XML

Tags: xml, parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to parse XML data in Snowflake with a bit of a different structure.

Here is what the XML looks like (which is a sub portion of a larger XML, result from the following query):

```
select xmlget("ProductXML", 'custom-attributes') from TABLENAME
```

Sample of 1 XML entry

```
<custom-attributes>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="AnimalType">Chat</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="availableForInStorePickup">true</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="bagFormat">003</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="countryOfOrigin">US</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="flavor">
  <value>030</value>
 </custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="grossWeight">3.310</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="isDiscontinued">false</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="isDropShip">false</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="netWeight">3.180</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="packagingHeight">26.700</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="packagingLength">13.300</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="packagingWidth">44.500</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="weightUnit">KG</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
```

I would like to retrieve specific attribute IDs, like AnimalType or netWeight, which are present on all records. But they are all under the same 'custome-attribute' tag...

When I parse it with a simple xmlget fonction, Snowflake gives me what appears to be random order

```
select 
    xmlget(xmlget("ProductXML", 'custom-attributes'),'custom-attribute',4):"@attribute-id",
    xmlget(xmlget("ProductXML", 'custom-attributes'),'custom-attribute'):"$",
    get(xmlget("ProductXML", 'custom-attributes'),'@')
 from 
MYTABLE
```

How can I make sure I get the specific attribute-id (like AnimalType or netWeight) in my result set? And not the random line I see with the above query?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So with this CTE for fake data:

```
with TABLENAME("ProductXML") as (
select parse_xml('
<root>
<custom-attributes>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="AnimalType">Chat</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="availableForInStorePickup">true</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="bagFormat">003</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="countryOfOrigin">US</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="flavor">
  <value>030</value>
 </custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="grossWeight">3.310</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="isDiscontinued">false</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="isDropShip">false</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="netWeight">3.180</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="packagingHeight">26.700</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="packagingLength">13.300</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="packagingWidth">44.500</custom-attribute>
 <custom-attribute attribute-id="weightUnit">KG</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
</root>')
)
```

I would normally first check I can get the parts as rows:

```
select 
    f.value:"@attribute-id" as attrib_id
    ,f.value:"$" as attrib_content
 from TABLENAME,
    TABLE(flatten(input=>xmlget("ProductXML", 'custom-attributes'):"$", mode=>'ARRAY')) f
```

gives:

| ATTRIB_ID | ATTRIB_CONTENT |
| --- | --- |
| "AnimalType" | "Chat" |
| "availableForInStorePickup" | true |
| "bagFormat" | "003" |
| "countryOfOrigin" | "US" |
| "flavor" | 030 |
| "grossWeight" | 3.31 |
| "isDiscontinued" | false |
| "isDropShip" | false |
| "netWeight" | 3.18 |
| "packagingHeight" | 26.7 |
| "packagingLength" | 13.3 |
| "packagingWidth" | 44.5 |
| "weightUnit" | "KG" |

Then you can roll those back up, and select the wanted fields. The pulling apart allows for the values to be in position independent locations.

```
select 
     max(iff(f.value:"@attribute-id"='grossWeight', f.value:"$"::float,null))  as grossWeight
    ,max(iff(f.value:"@attribute-id"='isDropShip', f.value:"$"::boolean,null)) as isDropShip
    ,max(iff(f.value:"@attribute-id"='weightUnit', f.value:"$"::text,null))  as weightUnit
 from TABLENAME,
    TABLE(flatten(input=>xmlget("ProductXML", 'custom-attributes'):"$", mode=>'ARRAY')) f
group by f.seq
```

giving what I think you want as:

| GROSSWEIGHT | ISDROPSHIP | WEIGHTUNIT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3.31 | FALSE | KG |

Comment: Simon - you are a living legend! Thanks so much! I was missing the flatten portion. AWESOME!!!!!!

Comment: Hope it will help the community!